# How do I connect to and make a request to the following sample SOAP service in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

It's just come to my attention that I'm going to have to interact with a SOAP API in the near future. Up until now though, I've only ever used REST APIs and never a SOAP API.

I've been reading about SOAP APIs and thus far my (very likely wrong) understanding is as follows:

- You first connect to the SOAP service. When you connect, you type in the URL to the WSDL file, which then tells you which "services" (am I using the right term here?) are available via the SOAP API.
- Once you know which service you want to call, you call the service with the necessary parameters and send an XML request to the SOAP server, upon which it sends back an XML response.

I have two questions:

1. Is my understanding of SOAP above is even correct to begin with?
2. How do I use PHP to connect and make requests to the following sample SOAP API: http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather

(If the sample SOAP API linked above is not a very good one, then I'm open to learning how to use SOAP with any other sample SOAP APIs that are available.)

---

**Edit**: pawelwaw, I wrote the following sample code to test everything out, but it seems like no matter what value I use for `CityName` in the `GetWeather` operation, I get no data back. Is my understanding incorrect, or is the SOAP API just not very good?

```
<?php

  $client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl');

  echo '<h2>Types:</h2>';
  echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($client->__getTypes());
  echo '</pre>';

  echo '<h2>Functions:</h2>';
  echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
  echo '</pre>';

  echo '<h2>GetCitiesByCountry:</h2>';
  echo '<pre>';
    echo htmlentities($client->GetCitiesByCountry([
      'CountryName' => 'Poland'
    ])->GetCitiesByCountryResult);
  echo '</pre>';

  echo '<h2>GetWeather:</h2>';
  echo '<pre>';  
    var_dump($client->GetWeather([
      'CityName' => 'Krakow',
      'CountryName' => 'Poland'
    ]));
  echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ussally use SOAP api.
And for this service 
You can use this sample code to get Cities of Country

```
<?php
  $api = new SoapClient ( 'http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL' );
  $res = $api->GetCitiesByCountry(array( 'CountryName' =>"Poland"));

  var_dump($res);
?>
```

then you are able to run 2nd method of this api to get Weather
http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather

I hope, it helps.

It seems that function GetWeather ( http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather ) don't work correctly. when I filled values manually on site then there is no response with data, but for function GetCitiesByCountry ( http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetCitiesByCountry )  returns data.
I hadn't many expirience with API, but this should work, in my opinion there is a problem with this function in SOAP, because don't work via http also.
I tested it via REST, and this function don't work according to specification.

Comment: pawelwaw, thanks a lot for the answer. It makes a lot of sense. Please see the edit in my question for an addition question though. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that function GetWeather don't work. You can use one of those apis, some of them are free https://superdevresources.com/weather-forecast-api-for-developing-apps/

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. I was more just trying to make sure I understood how to properly use a SOAP service in PHP and that the API itself was broken (and not my understanding).